# logrotate fails to run Java postrotate program

Tags: systemd, logrotate, grsec

Somewhat recent versions of logrotate fail to execute postrotate actions that invoke Java when logrotate is started via systemd. In my logs I see:

```
logrotate[123]: Error occurred during initialization of VM
logrotate[123]: Failed to mark memory page as executable - check if grsecurity/PaX is enabled
```

Answer (score 2):

The following commit added hardening options to logrotate's systemd script:
https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate/commit/1008bdf391e35684d8eeb2217c859f11e273ebb3

These changes were released with logrotate v3.14 (also included in Debian 10, released July 2019).

One of the configured options (`MemoryDenyWriteExecute=true`) causes execution of Java programs to fail. Setting this option to `false` fixes the issue for me, possibly making the system less secured/hardened.